# How to use .next() by dynamically-filled content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery, carousel

I'm doing a simple photo gallery, its implemented almost everything, now I want to realize the Next and Prev buttons. 
But do not understand how I can use the .next ()-function in my code (see JsFiddle). Im newbie in jQuery.

All images are loaded using PHP and AJAX

if i use:

```
 $(".thumb").next()....
```

so i get all Elements with a class .thumb...

I could also write a class to each image ala ".thumb .image1"...
Is there maybe a better solution exists?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akdes/kfbp5ru4/1/)

Best regards, Alex

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/akdes/kfbp5ru4/12/)

Not with .next() Function, just got index of the element in my main-div...

```
var imageIndex = $(this).index();
```